# Retrieving user information in ArcGIS Server token protected geoprocessing service using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, authentication

I have a geoprocessing service on ArcGIS server 10.3 that is protected with tokens.

This GP Service is a python script. Is it possible to retrieve the user information, such username and password, from inside the script using the token passed as parameter?

Is there a way with arcpy to retrieve user information from a valid token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not mentioned anywhere in any esri doc, but there is a way to have the user info from a token. You have to use `arcgis/rest/self` service like this:

```
https://<servername>:6443/arcgis/rest/self?f=pjson&token=<token>
```

From python you can call that service using `httplib` or other library

```
import arcpy
import json
from httplib import HTTPConnection
from urllib import urlencode

class MyGPService:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.token = arcpy.getParameter(0)

    def getUserFromToken(self):
        try:
           params = urlencode({"token": self.token, "f": "json"})
           headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
           httpConn = HTTPConnection(SERVER_BASE_URL, SERVER_PORT)
           httpConn.request("POST", "/arcgis/rest/self", params, headers)
           response = httpConn.getresponse()
           getUserResponse = json.loads(response.read())
           httpConn.close()
        except Exception as e:
           arcpy.AddError(e)

        if "error" in getUserResponse:
           arcpy.AddError(getUserResponse["error"])
        else:
           return getUserResponse["user"]
```